# Python pandas write resulted dataframe to xlsm without losing the macro

Tags: python, excel, vba, pandas

I have a lot of excel files that I need to compile into a single excel file, and then copy the compiled one into an existing excel file (with macro / .xlsm) in a certain sheet.

I solved the first problem (compiling multiple excel files into a single excel file). The resulted dataframe is saved in .csv format. The resulted file looks like this.
[image: the resulted dataframe]

Until here there is no issue. The next step that I am struggling to find out how to do it.

From the resulted dataframe I want to "copy-and-paste" the dataframe to the existing excel file with macro (.xlsm) in the sheet "Source" at the corresponding headers. The existing excel file looks like this.
[image: target excel file]

As you may see from the picture above, I want to skip writing any data in the column A since the cells within this column is full of formula. I want to write the resulted dataframe in the column B to column Q within the existing excel file. However, before writing the data, I want delete all the existing data in all cells (except in the cells within column A).

So basically I want to do the following:

1. delete all the values in the cells in the column B to column Q in
   the existing xlsm file (in the sheet "Source")
2. write the new values from the resulted dataframe to column B until column Q
3. save the excel file back with the same name without losing the macro

Any feedback will be much appreciated! Thanks!

Regards,

Arnold

Comment: start recording a macro while doing the actions you listed. then take its resulting code and work on it.

Comment: Basically, what I understand from your question is that you wanted to replace the values from column B to Q in your data frame right?
If that is the case then you can use `df.drop(<column name>)` and the add new columns by `df[<column name>] = <your values>`

Comment: @user3598756 thanks for the comment. However, I am not an excel savvy, so I do not completely understand your suggestion. Seems you are suggesting to work on the copy-and-paste data manually. Whilst I am trying to automate my compiling work. Nevertheless, thanks for your advice!

Comment: @ShubhamNamdeo Yes you are right. I need to replace the values in the column B to column Q with the new values that I have already generated. So I need to know how to "write" the generated values (the new values) to the existing xlsm file without losing the macro in the excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry a bit late to come back updating my question. Finally I have solved my problem with openpyxl package.

So here is my final code:

```
import openpyxl
import os
import string
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

path = #folder directory
target_file = #excel filename
sheetname = #working sheet that you wish to work on with

filename = os.path.join(path, target_file)

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename, keep_vba=True)
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheetname)

# To Erase All Values within Selected Columns
d = dict()
for x, y in zip(range(1, 27), string.ascii_lowercase):
    d[x] = y.upper()

max_row = sheet.max_row
max_col = sheet.max_column

for row in range(max_row):
    row += 1
    if row == 1: continue
    for col in range(max_col):
        col += 1
        if col == 1: continue
        sheet['{}{}'.format(d[col], row)] = None

# To Write Values to the Blank Worksheet
path_dataframe = # folder directory to the csv file
target_compiled = # csv filename
filename_compiled = os.path.join(path_compiled, target_compiled)

compiled = pd.read_csv(filename_compiled, low_memory=False, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")

for row in range(len(compiled.index)):
    row += 1
    if row == 1: continue # I do not want to change the value in row 1 in excel file because they are headers
    for col in range(max_col): 
        col += 1
        if col == 1: continue # I do not want to change the values in column 1 in excel file since they contain formula
        value = compiled.iloc[row-2][col-2]
        if type(value) is str: value = value
        elif type(value) is np.float64: value = float(value)
        elif type(value) is np.int64: value = int(value)
        sheet['{}{}'.format(d[col], row)] = value

wb.save(filename)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the follwing solution based on openpyxl. What I learned is that xlsxwriter is not able to open existing excel files. Therefore, my approach is based on openpyxl.

```
import pandas as pd 
import openpyxl # one excel reader/writer compatible with pandas

book = openpyxl.load_workbook('input.xlsm', keep_vba = True) # Load existing .xlsm file

with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsm', engine='openpyxl') as writer: # open a writer instance with the filename of the 
    
    writer.book = book # Hand over input workbook
    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets) # Hand over worksheets
    writer.vba_archive = book.vba_archive # Hand over VBA information 


    df_write.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Sheet1', columns = ['A'],
                  header = False, index = False,
                  startrow = 1, startcol = 0)
    # Writes a column A of the Dataframe into the excel sheet 'Sheet1', which can 
    # already be present in input.xlsm, to row 1, col 0

    
    writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your csv import into spreadsheet can be handled with an Excel VBA macro using [QueryTables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837764.aspx) consider having Python replicate VBA with a COM interface to the Excel Object Library. All previous macro code remains intact as nothing is overwritten but cell data. **Note**: Below assumes you are using Excel for Windows.

Using the `win32com` library, Python can replicate almost anything VBA does. In fact, you will come to know VBA is an add-on reference in Office applications and never a native, built-in object and does the same COM interfacing! See first selected item in `Tools\References` in your IDE.

```
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client as win32

# ...same pandas code...    
macrofile = "C:\\Path\\To\\Macro\\Workbook.xlsm"
strfile = "C:\\Path\\To\\CSV\\Output.csv"
df.to_csv(strfile)

try:
    xl = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(macrofile)

    # DELETE PREVIOUS DATA
    wb.Sheets("Source").Range("B:Q").EntireColumn.Delete()

    # ADD QUERYTABLE (SPECIFYING DESTINATION CELL START)
    qt = wb.Sheets("Source").QueryTables.Add(Connection="TEXT;" + strfile, 
                                             Destination=wb.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 2))
    qt.TextFileParseType = 1
    qt.TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    qt.TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    qt.TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    qt.TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    qt.TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    qt.Refresh(BackgroundQuery=False)

    # REMOVE QUERYTABLE
    for qt in wb.Sheets("Source").QueryTables:
        qt.Delete()

    # CLOSES WORKBOOK AND SAVES CHANGES
    wb.Close(True)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

finally:    
    qt = None
    wb = None
    xl = None
```

---

Alternatively, create a new macro in VBA (placed in a standalone module) and have Python call it, passing the csv file path as parameter:

**VBA**

```vb
Public Sub ImportCSV(strfile As String)
    Dim qt As QueryTable

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Source").Range("B:Q").EntireColumn.Delete

    ' ADD QUERYTABLE
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Source").QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & strfile, _
        Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 2))
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False

            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    ' REMOVE QUERYTABLE
    For Each qt In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).QueryTables
        qt.Delete
    Next qt

    Set qt = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Python**

```
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client as win32

# ...same pandas code...    
macrofile = "C:\\Path\\To\\Macro\\Workbook.xlsm"
strfile = "C:\\Path\\To\\CSV\\Output.csv"
df.to_csv(strfile)

try:
    xl = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

    wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(macrofile)
    xl.Application.Run('ImportCSV', strfile)

    wb.Close(True)
    xl.Quit

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

finally:    
    wb = None
    xl = None
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I will try and come back once I get the results! Thanks for your time and effort in addressing my problem!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can use xlwings

```
import pandas as pd
import xlwings

df = pd.DataFrame({
  "A": [420, 380, 390],
  "B": [50, 40, 45],
  "C": [60, 50, 20]
})


with xlwings.App(visible=False) as app:
    wb = xlwings.Book('Test.xlsm')    
    ws = wb.sheets('MySheet')
    ws.range('B1:D50').delete(shift='up') #if you want to delete the values, if not they will be overwritten
    ws.range('B1:D1').options(header=False, index=False).value = df[['A','B','C' ]]
    wb.save()
    wb.close()
```